# Finding elements parlallel to main diagonal in a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, parallel-processing, element

I have to make a program that finds the sums of the elements of matrix which are located parallel to main diagonal. I have no idea how to find the elements which are parallel to the main diagonal. The i==j works only for the main diagonal only. Let's say we have a matrix like this:

```
22 5 6 4
32 45 7 9
1 21 43 6
7 5 9 11
```

I have to find the sums separately: 4; 6+9; 5+7+6; 22+45+43+11; 32+21+9; 1+5; 7

```
After the changes the code become like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#define N 50
void enter_matrix (float m[N][N],int n){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("Enter %d %d element of the matrix: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%f",&m[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void show_matrix(float m[N][N],int n){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%.2f\t",m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int find_sums(float m[N][N],float sum[100],int n){
    int j=0;
    for(int offset = -n+1; offset < n; ++offset) {
    float sum1 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-fabs(offset); ++i) {
        if(offset <= 0) {
           sum1 += m[i][i-offset];
        }
        else {
           sum1 += m[i+offset][i];
        }
        sum[j]=sum1;j++;printf("%.2f \n",sum1);
    }
    }
    return j;
}

int find_max(float sum, int j){
    int i,maxn;float *s,max=0;s=&sum;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        if(*(s+1)>max){
            max=*(s+1);
            maxn=i;
        }
    }
    return maxn;
}

int find_min(float sum, int j){
    int i,minn;
    float *s;
    s=&sum;float min=*(s+0);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        if(*(s+1)<min){
            min=*(s+1);
            minn=i;
        }
    }
    return minn;
}

void main(){
    float matrix [N][N], sum[100],*s;
    int  n,j,maxn,minn;
    s=sum;

    do{
        printf("Enter matrix dimension (between 1 and 50):");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    while(n<=0||n>50);
    enter_matrix(matrix,n);
    show_matrix(matrix,n);
    j=find_sums(matrix,sum,n);
    maxn=find_max(sum[100],j);
    minn=find_min(sum[100],j);
    printf("Maximum sum is equal to %.2f, at line %d\n",sum[maxn],maxn+1);
    printf("Minimum sum is equal to %.2f, at line %d\n",sum[minn],minn+1);
}
```

And the output is like this:

```
Enter matrix dimension (between 1 and 50):3
Enter 1 1 element of the matrix: 1
Enter 1 2 element of the matrix: 2
Enter 1 3 element of the matrix: 3
Enter 2 1 element of the matrix: 4
Enter 2 2 element of the matrix: 5
Enter 2 3 element of the matrix: 6
Enter 3 1 element of the matrix: 7
Enter 3 2 element of the matrix: 8
Enter 3 3 element of the matrix: 9
1.00    2.00    3.00
4.00    5.00    6.00
7.00    8.00    9.00
3.00
2.00
8.00
1.00
6.00
15.00
4.00
12.00
7.00
Maximum sum is equal to 3.00, at line 1
Minimum sum is equal to 3.00, at line 1
Press any key to continue
```

It is making some extra sums not only the full lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: You were [close](https://ideone.com/5HhRQQ), but among other things, `sum[j] = ...` should be outside the inner loop. May I ask why have you tagged a [C program](https://ideone.com/06058d) as C++?

Answer (score 0):

Untested and from the top of my head:

```
int n;
double A[n][n]

for(int offset = -n+1; offset < n; ++offset) {
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-std::abs(offset); ++i) {
        if(offset <= 0) {
           sum += A[i][i-offset];
        else {
           sum += A[i+offset][i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

For negative offset this prints the sums of the upper parallel diagonals and for positive offset the sums of the lower parallel diagonals. The first loop can trivially be parallelized, the print statement is the only critical part.

Comment: Thanks but i need the sum of every line separately so i can store them in a separate array. For example 6+9 in sum[1], and 5+7+6 in sum[2] and so on

Comment: @user3058396 What prevents you to change this code adding an array (say `double d[2n-1];`), a variable (`int j = 0`?) and two statements after the inner loop end (`a[j] = sum; ++j;`) ? ;)

Comment: @user3058396 See  Bob__'s comment on the question: you have to put `a[j] = sum; ++j;` at the position where I wrote to print statement `std::cout << sum << std::endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

For those diagonals, it holds that j = i + z for z depending on the diagonal, reaching from -(height-1) to (width-1).

This results in the following algorithm (with the solution array being able to handle negative indices - you have to alter that by some offset):

```
Array<R> diagonalSums (Matrix<R> m)

    initialize Array<R> solution in according size with all entries initialized to zero

    for each cell i,j in m:
        find z so that j = i + z (z = j - i)
        solution[z] += m(i,j)

    return solution
```

I think that you do something like that with your offset, but you try to find a way to go from z to the sum that belongs to that z, which is only unnecessarily confusing, at least when you want to compute all sums anyway (your way is better if only one sum is needed). My approach simply goes over all cells and then adds it at the according place.

I used an array that has negative indices and in order to increase readability, I'd advise that you do too, that is to create a class that can do that.